# Shading effects not showing in layout

Tags: shaders

I've edited an eyeball in the shading editor however I am unable to see the shading effects in 'layout' it just shows the mesh. However I can see shading effects under 'shading' tab

---

This is the eyeball in shading

[image]

Comment: Hello :). Please add some screenshots to illustrate the problem.

Comment: What preview mode are you in? By default, "layout" uses solid preview, whereas the shading tab uses "material preview" (aka "lookdev"). Change it by either clicking one of the (two rightmost) little circles in the top right of the window, or change mode by pressing Z in the 3D viewport and picking a preview mode from the pie menu (Material preview or Rendered preview are the ones you want - they display materials)

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!

Answer (score -1):

This is the mesh in layout where it doesnt show the colours
[image]

Comment: See my comment above